# WiFi networks don't show up in windows 10, but I am connected

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, notification-area, wifi-driver

I am having a problem when I left-click on the WiFi icon in my system tray, the popup is blank, then it will close by itself, never showing anything.  See picture.

[image: WiFi Blank]

When I right-click on the WiFi icon, and go to "Open Network & Internet Settings", then click on "Show available networks" it will try to open the same system tray popup like in the picture, then it will close.

Also, if after I open "Network & Internet Settings", if I click on Wi-Fi, the application fails and closes. See picture.

[image: Settings Close]

Once in a while, when I click on the WiFi icon in the system tray, it will work as intended.

The only way I can look at the networks, is to lock my computer and then from the lock screen, select a network.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What have you tried to fix it?  I would recommend downloading the wifi driver from the computer manufacturer's website, uninstalling the current wifi driver, rebooting, then installing the downloaded wifi driver.

Comment: tried that, didn't resolve the problem